# How does the Cloak of Resistance's caster level requirement function if a crafter does not meet its prerequisites?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, caster-level

How does not meeting the prerequisite in order to craft a *cloak of resistance* function?

I have a 7th-level wizard with craft wondrous item. He can do a +2 version no problem, not missing requirements.

- Does he gain +5 or +10 to the DC if he attempts to do a +4 version of the cloak?
- Can he actually do the +3 or +4 versions of the cloak?

This is mostly specific for *cloak of resistance*, since it requires a 3 caster levels per each +1 for crafting purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### +5 to DC

The [rules for creating magic items](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Magic%20Item%20Creation&Category=Magic%20Items) state (emphasis mine):

> Note that all items have prerequisites in their descriptions. These prerequisites must be met for the item to be created. Most of the time, they take the form of spells that must be known by the item’s creator (although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed). *The DC to create a magic item increases by +5 for each prerequisite the caster does not meet.* The only exception to this is the requisite item creation feat, which is mandatory. In addition, you cannot create potions, spell-trigger, or spell-completion magic items without meeting their spell prerequisites.

[Cloak of Resistance](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Cloak%20of%20Resistance1) lists the following for it's crafting requirements:

> Requirements Craft Wondrous Item, resistance, *creator's caster level must be at least three times the cloak's bonus*;

The cloak only has one requirement for caster level, that you have three times the caster level of its bonus. None of the caster level requirements for the other versions apply to it.

If this was the only requirement you didn't meet, you would be able to craft it with only a +5 to the DC.

Comment: I added one small additional question, can you regard  it please? :)